# Is it possible to use Microsoft Software Radio (Sora) with Cellular signals?

Tags: wifi, software, hardware, cellphone

I'm interested in learning about cellular data and protocols and came across [Microsoft Software Radio (Sora).](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/sora/#Kit)

Although this board is originally intended for Wifi signals (or so it sees) Is it possible to use this board (and some unknown related add-in) to interact with Cellular signals? (GSM, etc)

If no, what other tools are there?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to receive cellular telephone signals, you will probably run afoul of the FCC which prohibits private reception of cellular signals.  That is why all shortwave radios and scanners sold in the US have the cellular telephone bands blocked.